# Generating encrypted private key file with git-bash

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, git-bash

I am trying to generate a encrytpted private/public key using the code example given here

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth.html

```
$ openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8
```

however it just generates an empty file.  Is there something I'm missing perhaps?

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: I copy-pasted the command directly from your question and it generated the file with a private key in it. Must be something specific to your environment that's the issue?

Comment: Thankyou for your response.   when I use the examples given here: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenSSL/Creating-RSA-Keys-using-OpenSSL 

it generates a file with content.  Also what does the '$' mean - sorry Im a newbie.  When I try to run the same line in snowsql it just doesnt do anything.

Comment: This command needs to be run on the command line of your computer, not within Snowsql. $ is the command prompt in many (usually linux-based) operating systems

Comment: thanks for that.  Im running the command in git-bash. when I execute it I just get a message:

Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
................................................................................................................+++++
...............+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)

And it creates an empty file. Can't see what is going wrong

Comment: Are you running git bash on windows or..? Try running it in regular bash?

Comment: @Windswept I get same with gitbash `$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1u  30 May 2023`, but running command from powershell at least generates a file